# Image edited and saved in C# can not be read by ffmpeg

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg

I have template image (template.jpg) on which I draw some text (13.07.2017.) and than I save it to another location (temp/intro.jpg).

Than I want to convert that and some other images into video with ffmpeg.

If I run command

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

Those images gets concentrated into one video file. Problem is that this image edited through C# is black in final video.

If I for example open that C# created image in Adobe Fireworks and just save it (CTRL+S) without changing anything, and re run ffmpeg command everything is fine.

This is code which I use to add text to template image

```
//INTRO IMAGE CREATION
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(1280, 720);
image.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
};

//template
Bitmap back = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + @"\Templates\template.jpg");
g.DrawImage(back, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

//date
string Date = dateIntro.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.");
var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 206, 33, 39));
Font font = new Font("Ubuntu", 97, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
float x = 617;
float y = 530;

g.DrawString(Date, font, brush, x, y, format);
g.Flush();
image.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\temp\intro.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image.Dispose();
```

Image created this way can be opened and viewed in any program except converted to video with ffmpeg.

Is there anything I'm missing while adding text and saving image in C#?

Comment: Works fine for me using that code. Could it be that ffmpeg is being forced to output a colour space that your player doesn't like? Can you force it with `-vf format=yuv420p` when making the MP4?

Comment: I don't get it but it actually worked by replacing `-vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p"` with just `-vf format=yuv420p` Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan wrote in his comment

> Works fine for me using that code. Could it be that ffmpeg is being
>   forced to output a colour space that your player doesn't like? Can you
>   force it with `-vf format=yuv420p` when making the MP4?

changing

```
-vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p"
```

into

```
-vf format=yuv420p
```

Solved my problem